# Google maps markers , polyline and window info from array

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a polyline with markers and window-info from array point (from a ajax page)
***This is index Page codes:***

```
var gmarkers = []; 
var map = null;
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.332702, 53.177137),
    // mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });

function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

***My Ajax Page:***

```
var polylines = [];

var beaches = [
    ['Bondi Beach',10,15, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach',11,16, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach',13,15, 3],
    ['Manly Beach',13,17, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach',12,10, 1]
];

for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var polylines = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);

    var marker = createMarker(myLatLng,"This place",beach[0])
}

var routes = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polylines,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
    strokeWeight: 4
});

routes.setMap(map);
```

After I call the `Ajax Page` , markers add with window-info , but route polyline don't show , where is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I call the Ajax Page , markers add with window-info , but route polyline don't show , where is the problem ?

Yes.  polylines is an array here:

```
var polylines = [];
```

Here you overwrite it with a single google.maps.LatLng:

```
var polylines = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
polylines.push(new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]));
```